# How to use Range as one of parameters for POST Data to rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, range, factory-bot

The database migration has `experience` field defined as a range

```
class CreateJobPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :job_posts do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false, limit: 100
      t.string :location, null: false, limit: 100
      t.int4range :experience, null: false
      t.text :description, null: false
      t.text :skills, null:false
      t.boolean :active, null: false, default: false
      t.string :seo_meta_keywords, array: true, null: false
      t.string :seo_meta_description, null: false, limit: 150

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :job_posts, :name, unique: true
    add_index :job_posts, :location
    add_index :job_posts, :active
  end
end
```

Now while writing tests, I have FactoryGirl defined some models like so

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :job_post do
        name "DevOps Coach"
        location "Bangalore"
        experience (4..10)
        description 'Test Description'
        skills 'Test Skills'
        active true
        seo_meta_keywords ['keywords','keywords']
        seo_meta_description 'dummy descriptions'
    end
end
```

And in the controller

```
def job_post_params
  params.require(:job_post).permit(:name, :location, :experience, :description, :skills, :active, :seo_meta_description, seo_meta_keywords: [])
end
```

The attribute hashes are initialised as expected

```
[89, 98] in /Users/anadi/Code/bauji/spec/controllers/job_posts_controller_spec.rb
   89:
   90:     context "with invalid params" do
   91:       it "returns a success response (i.e. to display the 'new' template)" do
   92:         byebug
   93:         temp = invalid_attributes
=> 94:         post :create, params: {job_post: invalid_attributes}, session: valid_session
   95:         expect(response).to be_success
   96:       end
   97:     end
   98:   end
(byebug) temp
{:name=>"No Name", :location=>"Nay", :experience=>4..10, :description=>"Test Description", :skills=>"Test skills", :active=>true, :seo_meta_keywords=>["keywords", "keywords"], :seo_meta_description=>"dummy descriptions"}
```

but the POST & PUT method tests fail because `:experience` attribute is nil for controller

```
[24, 33] in /Users/anadi/Code/bauji/app/controllers/job_posts_controller.rb
   24:   # POST /job_posts
   25:   # POST /job_posts.json
   26:   def create
   27:     byebug
   28:     @job_post = JobPost.new(job_post_params)
=> 29:     respond_to do |format|
   30:       if @job_post.save
   31:         format.html { redirect_to @job_post, notice: 'Job post was successfully created.' }
   32:         format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @job_post }
   33:       else
(byebug) @job_post
#<JobPost:0x007fda5fb21920>
(byebug) @job_post.experience
*** ArgumentError Exception: bad value for range

nil
```

Solution:

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def job_post_params
  raw_post_params = params.require(:job_post).permit(:name, :location, :experience, :description, :skills, :active, :seo_meta_description, seo_meta_keywords: [])
  range_begin, range_end = raw_post_params[:experience].split('..').map { |v| Integer(v) }
  raw_post_params[:experience] = Range.new(range_begin, range_end)
  raw_post_params
end
```

Could it be more compact?

Comment: Only :experience param is null?

Comment: yes, it takes other params without a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make the POST request, the `4..10` is most likely converted to a `String`: `"4..10"`. Try and parse the string in your controller with something similar to:

```
range_begin, range_end = params[:experience].split('..').map { |v| Integer(v) }
experience = Range.new(range_begin, range_end)
```

Then you can set that `experience` to attribute on your `JobPost`

Comment: Hi! yeah that helped fixing it, added the code in question, wondering if it can be lesser lines of code?